# Dojox.grid.DataGrid with empty Data

Tags: dojox.grid.datagrid, dojo

My problem is that the datagrid does not appear I need it to be empty so I can add items to do a relation with a existing FilteringSelect Formatter.

```
function formatter1() {
            var x = new FilteringSelect({
            name: "Account Select",
            //value: "1",
            store: remoteData,
            searchAttr: "name",
            onChange: function () {
                console.log("EI");
            }

        });
        x._destroyOnRemove=true;
        return x;
}
```

// Relations data grid

```
var DataRelations = { identifier: "id", items: [] };

storeRelations = new Write({data: DataRelations, clearOnClose: true });

var layoutRelations = [
    {'name': "Words", field: "word", width: 40 },
    {'name': "Account", field: "id", width: 40, formatter: formatter1 }

    //,{'name': "Accounts Available", field: "AccountsAvailable", width: 20, formatter: formatter1}
];

var gridRelations = new DataGrid({
        id: 'gridRelations',
        store: storeRelations,
        structure: layoutRelations,
    rowSelector: '10px'
});

/*append the new grid to the div*/
gridRelations.placeAt("gridDivRelations");

/*Call startup() to render the grid*/
gridRelations.startup();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a working jsfiddle based on your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/LFk8Z/

You need to specify a width and a height for the DIV container of the grid. Maybe that was the initial problem. Also you need to load the grid css resources. Your formatter function did not have a paramater, but you need to specify one:

```
function formatter1(x) {
// Format cell value (which is in x) in here.
}
```

Comment: My problem was really more of the div sizes that woren't specified. After placing that it displayed nicely. Thank you